# Конфликт кода

Tags: jquery

Добрый день, уважаемые.

Имеется код.

```
$(document).ready(init);

function init() {
    $('.slot41').hover(hOver, hOut);
}

function hOver() {
    $('.slot4').css("background-image", "url(images/slot4.gif)");
}

function hOut() {
    $('.slot4').css("background-image", "url(images/slot4.png)");
}
```

На странице должно быть 6 объектов, работающих по такому коду независимо друг от друга. Проблема заключается в следующем, что если добавить еще один код, например, такой

```
$(document).ready(initt);

function initt() {
    $('.slot11').hover(hOver, hOut);
}

function hOver() {
    $('.slot1').css("background-image", "url(images/slot1.gif)");
}

function hOut() {
    $('.slot1').css("background-image", "url(images/slot1.png)");
}
```

то предыдущий перестает работать. Помогите разобраться из-за чего конфликт.

Comment: @alexsis20102, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку 101010 редактора.

Comment: рукалицо - иначе не сказать...

Comment: Как сделать чтобы была не рукалицо ???

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(init);

function init() {
    $('.slot41').hover(hOver4, hOut4);
    $('.slot11').hover(hOver1, hOut1);
}
function hOver4() {
    $('.slot4').css("background-image", "url(images/slot4.gif)");
}
function hOut4() {
    $('.slot4').css("background-image", "url(images/slot4.png)");
}
function hOver1() {
    $('.slot1').css("background-image", "url(images/slot1.gif)");
}
function hOut1() {
    $('.slot1').css("background-image", "url(images/slot1.png)");
}
```

Может так.

Answer (score 1):

> Как сделать чтобы была не рукалицо ???

```
$("some element").hover(
  function () {
    //some actions
  },
  function () {
    //some actions
  }
);
```

в вашем случае:

```
$(".slot11").hover(
  function () {
    $(this).css("background-image", "url(images/slot1.gif)");
  },
  function () {
    $(this).css("background-image", "url(images/slot1.png)");
  }
);
```

**UPD:** Не верно прочел вопрос... извиняюсь!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{

function action(element, color)
{
    color = color.split(",");

    $(element).hover(
        function()
        {
            $(this).css("color", color[0]);
        },
        function()
        {
            $(this).css("color", color[1]);
        }
    );
}

action("#div1", "red,green");
action("#div2", "red,green");
// и т.д.

});
</script>
<div id="div1">Hover My</div>
<div id="div2">Hover My</div>
<!-- и т.д. //-->
```

З.Ы. Суть работы ясна, перекручивайте под свои потребности!

color можно заменить на image и передавать значение в виде `"image.png,image.gif"`

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="slot" data-image="slot1">slot1</div>
<div class="slot" data-image="slot2">slot2</div>
<div class="slot" data-image="slot3">slot3</div>
<div class="slot" data-image="slot4">slot4</div>
```

теперь jQuery:

```
$(function(){
    $('.slot').hover(hOver, hOut);
});

function hOver() {
    var img = $(this).data('image');
    $(this).css("background-image", "url(images/" + img + ".gif)");
}

function hOut() {   
    var img = $(this).data('image');
    $(this).css("background-image", "url(images/" + img + ".png)");
}
```